# Collate child elements

Tags: xslt

For every property element of type=CHOICE, I want to collate the choice elements. So given:

```
<property>
  <name>lookup_mode</name>
  <type>CHOICE</type>
  <defaultValue>1</defaultValue>
  <choices>
      <value>1</value>
      <value>2</value>
      <value>3</value>
  </choices>
  <choiceNames>
      <value>Challenge</value>
      <value>Pass Through</value>
      <value>Not Supported</value>
  </choiceNames>
</property>
```

the output is:

```
<property>
  <name>lookup_mode</name>
  <type>CHOICE</type>
  <defaultValue>1</defaultValue>
  <choices>
    <choice>
      <index>1</index>
      <choiceName>Challenge</choiceName>
    </choice>
    <choice>
      <index>2</index>
      <choiceName>Pass Through</choiceName>
    </choice>
    <choice>
      <index>3</index>
      <choiceName>Not Supported</choiceName>
    </choice>
  </choices>
</property>
```

I tried template:

```
<xsl:template match="propertyDescriptor[type/text()='CHOICE']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <choices>
      <xsl:for-each select="choices/value">
        <choice>
          <index><xsl:value-of select="."/></index>
          <choiceName><xsl:value-of select="../../choiceNames/value"/></choiceName>
        </choice>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </choices>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If I use the choice as index for the loop then choiceName values are repeated for every choice, and vice versa:

```
<property>
   <choices>
      <choice>
         <index>0</index>
         <choiceName>Challenge Pass Through Not Supported</choiceName>
      </choice>
      <choice>
         <index>1</index>
         <choiceName>Challenge Pass Through Not Supported</choiceName>
      </choice>
      <choice>
         <index>2</index>
         <choiceName>Challenge Pass Through Not Supported</choiceName>
      </choice>
   </choices>
   ...
```

I'm following XSLT Jumpstarter (2015) where the author tackles similar operations in Chapter 6, Changing the Structure and order of Content. Element collation (like printer page collation) is not covered. I would think there was some stock pattern to follow?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider to show us a minimal but complete stylesheet allowing us to reproduce the problem. Then we can fix it.

Comment: Please post your full attempt so that we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. Note that there's no `propertyDescriptor` element in your input.

Comment: Agreeing with previous comments: either you narrow down to a finer grain problem or you give more context/code. This will help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you are looking for can be achieved by:

```
<xsl:template match="property[type='CHOICE']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="name | type | defaultValue"/>
        <choices>
            <xsl:for-each select="choices/value">
                <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                <choice>
                    <index>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </index>
                    <choiceName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../choiceNames/value[$i]"/>
                    </choiceName>
                </choice>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </choices>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

The (main) reason why your attempt doesn't work is that your instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../choiceNames/value"/>
```

selects **all** `choiceNames/value` nodes and returns the string-value of either the first one (in XSLT 1.0) or all of them (in XSLT 2.0), without considering which `choices/value` node is the current one.